# How to use the Null assertion operator with instance fields

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I'm having trouble understanding how to type promote an object's field if it is nullable. Let's say I had the following Comment class and tried to access its one nullable field:

```
class Comment {
  final String? text;
  Comment(this.text); 
}

void main() {
  final comment = Comment("comment");
  
  if (comment.text!= null) {
    String text = comment!.text;
  }
}
```

The Dart compiler would give me an error for trying to assign a nullable variable to a non-nullable variable. From what I've gathered from looking into this topic, it's impossible to have type promotion with instance variables because instance variables can be modified which can then break the sound null-safety. I've seen the Null assertion operator (!.) being used in these circumstances, however it doesn't seem to work with fields, only with methods.

With dart null-safety, how should I go about assigning a nullable field such as String? to a non-nullable variable (String). To the same effect, how should I go about passing a nullable field to a function that requires a non-null argument.

Comment: You're putting the `!` in the wrong place.  `comment` is known to not be null; its *member* is what's not guaranteed to be non-null, so you need to do `String text = comment.text!;`.

Comment: This was exactly the answer I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can fix it in different ways:

1. Use local variable (recommended)

   ```dart
   final local = comment.text; // <-- Local variable
   if (local != null) {
     String text = local; 
   }
   ```
2. Use `?.` and provide a default value

   ```dart
   String text = comment?.text ?? 'Default value';
   ```
3. Use Bang operator `!`

   ```dart
   if (comment.text != null) {
     String text = comment.text!; // <-- Bang operator
   }
   ```

*Note: Bang operator can result in a runtime error if the `text` was `null`.*